# Книги по разработке ПО на примере одного приложения?

Tags: книги, проектирование, uml

Есть ли книги или что то еще, где описывается планирование, проектирование, UML строится поэтапно потом кодирование, тестирование, отладка?

А главное чтобы всё это не ограничилось чисто проектированием и абстрактным обзором с примером на 50 строк, а на выходе получилась модель нормальной программы.

Желательно язык С++ или java.

Просмотрел содержание очень многих и различных книжек. Но так и не нашел подходящей.

> - uml основы
> - быстрая разработка программ(Мартин)
> - Шаблон проектирования(Jesse Russell)
> - Непрерывное развертывание ПО. Автоматизация процессов сборки,
>   тестирования и внедрения новых версий
>   программ
> - Практическая программная инженерия на основе учебного примера
> - Рефакторинг. Улучшение существующего кода
>
> и еще множество, но содержания или оглавления там нету.
>
> Эти рекомендуют везде, но там либо
> проектирование либо шаблоны:
>
> - Гамма Э.и др. - Приемы объектно-ориентированного
>   проектирования. Паттерны
>   проектирования
> - Гради Буч - Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование с примерами
>   приложений
> - Александреску современное проектирование на C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте [Эрик Дж. Брауде - Технология разработки программного обеспечения](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1605279/).

Издание хорошее, перевод адекватный. На протяжении книги (которая по структуре похожа именно на учебное пособие) на примере одного проекта рассматриваются: управление проектом, сбор и анализ требований, архитектура, детальное проектирование, разработка, интеграция,  тестирование и контроль качества.

Еще есть интересная книга от Head First - [Управление разработкой ПО](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6258183/). Тоже планирование, проектирование, тестирование итп. Но там в каждой главе - отдельный пример, заточенный под эту главу. И в принципе все ведется по методологии близкой к Scrum (в книге у Эрика Брауде рассматриваются различные варианты).

Comment: Эрик Дж. Брауде - Технология разработки программного обеспечения.

Вот это то что надо. Пока всё замечательно объясняется.

Спасибо.